# VB Check if textbox does not have a specific numeric value

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I want to create an if statement that basically says...

If textbox does not contain "1" or "2" or "3" then
Show Messagebox

Could someone please tell me how I can format this properly?

Thanks, Cara

Comment: If you only have a few valid values, then make it painless for your user and use a combo box or a GroupBox with several radio buttons.  This way, there can be no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic way:

```
If textbox1.Text <> "1" AndAlso textbox1.Text <> "2" AndAlso textbox1.Text <> "3" Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid value. Valid are 1,2,3")
End If
```

The more readable and maintainable way. You could create a collection of valid values

```
Dim validValues = {"1", "2", "3"}
If Not validValues.Contains(textbox1.Text) Then
    Dim valids = String.Join(",", validValues)
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid value. Valid are " & valids)
End If
```